# Moving to details view with Image in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-asyncimage

I am new to swift. I am trying to achieve the requirement is when the spacific view record is selected I am want to move into details view with selected record including image. But the problems is the text property is display as expected not image failed.

so far I have tried `Image(people.avatar ?? "")` but actually it not working. even I can not see it into preview as well.

Here is the content view code ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct PeopleListView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: PeopleListViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if viewModel.customError != nil && !viewModel.refreshing {
                    alertView()
                } else {
                    if viewModel.refreshing {
                        progressView()
                    }
                    if viewModel.peopleLists.count > 0 && !viewModel.refreshing {

                        List(viewModel.peopleLists, id: \.self) { people in
                            NavigationLink(destination: PeopleDetailsView(people: people)) {

                                PeopleCellView(people: people)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    getToolBarView()
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("Employees List"))
        }.task{
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }
        .refreshable {
            await getDataFromAPI()
        }
    }

    func getDataFromAPI() async {
        await viewModel.getPeopleList(urlStr: NetworkURL.peopleUrl)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func getToolBarView() -> some View {
        Button {
            Task{
                await getDataFromAPI()
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                    .padding(.all, 10.0)
            }.fixedSize()
        }
        .cornerRadius(5.0)
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func progressView() -> some View {
        VStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(height: 180)
                .overlay{
                    VStack{
                        ProgressView().padding(50)
                        Text("Please Wait Message").font(.headline)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func alertView() -> some View {
        Text("").alert(isPresented: $viewModel.isErrorOccured) {
            Alert(title: Text("General_Error"), message: Text(viewModel.customError?.localizedDescription ?? ""),dismissButton: .default(Text("Okay")))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PeopleListView(viewModel: PeopleListViewModel(repository: PeopleRepositoryImplementation(networkManager: NetworkManager())))
    }
}
```

Here is code for cashed ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct CacheAsyncImage<Content>: View where Content: View {
    private let url: URL
    private let scale: CGFloat
    private let transaction: Transaction
    private let content: (AsyncImagePhase) -> Content

    init(url: URL,
         scale: CGFloat = 1.0,
         transaction: Transaction = Transaction(),
         @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (AsyncImagePhase) -> Content) {
        self.url = url
        self.scale = scale
        self.transaction = transaction
        self.content = content
    }
    var body: some View {
        if let cached = ImageCache[url] {
            content(.success(cached))
        } else {
            AsyncImage(url: url,
                       scale: scale,
                       transaction: transaction) { phase in
                cacheAndRender(phase: phase)
            }
        }
    }
    func cacheAndRender(phase: AsyncImagePhase) -> some View {
        if case .success(let image) = phase {
            ImageCache[url] = image
        }
        return content(phase)
    }
}

fileprivate class ImageCache {
    static private var cache: [URL: Image] = [:]
    static subscript(url: URL) -> Image? {
        get {
            ImageCache.cache[url]
        }
        set {
            ImageCache.cache[url] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Here is code for async image cashed ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct PeopleAsyncImageView: View {
    let url: URL
    private let imageWidth = 150.0
    private let cellHeight = 150.0

    var body: some View {
        CacheAsyncImage(
            url: url) { phase in
                switch phase {
                case .success(let image):
                    VStack {
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: imageWidth)
                            .padding(.trailing, 10)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                case .failure:
                    Image("placeholder-image")

                case .empty:
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        ProgressView()
                            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .red))
                    }
                @unknown default:
                    Image("placeholder-image")
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for view for respective properties including the image ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct PeopleCellView: View {
    let people: PeopleData
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if let url = URL(string: people.avatar ?? ""){
                PeopleAsyncImageView(url: url)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            }
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 5){
                Text("First Name: " +  people.firstName)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.headline)

                Text("Last Name: " + (people.lastName ?? ""))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)


                Text("Email: " + (people.email ?? ""))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .font(.subheadline)

            }
        }
    }
}
struct PeopleCellView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PeopleCellView(people: Constants.previewPeopleObj)
    }
}
```

Here is the details view code ..

```
import SwiftUI

struct PeopleDetailsView: View {
    
    @State var people: PeopleData
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {

            Image(people.avatar ?? "")
            Text("First Name - \(people.firstName)")
            Text("Last Name: \(people.lastName ?? " ")")
            Text("Email: \(people.email ?? " ")")

        }
    }
}
struct PeopleDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
       PeopleDetailsView(people: Constants.previewPeopleObj)
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the app ..

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the details view ..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, the `people.avatar` is just a URL, which your list is loading into a custom `PeopleAsyncImageView(url: url)`, which presumably downloads the image.
While in details you are trying to use `Image(people.avatar ?? "")` - that is passing a URL to `Image` view, which does not accept URLs.

So you have 2 options:

1. Use `PeopleAsyncImageView` in your `PeopleDetailsView` view
2. Or get your `PeopleAsyncImageView` to cache an image it downloaded (either on disk, or in memory) and pass it to `PeopleDetailsView`.

The first solution is simpler, just copy how the image is loaded in your list:

```
struct PeopleDetailsView: View {
    
    @State var people: PeopleData
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {

            // Image(people.avatar ?? "") <-- remove this
            if let url = URL(string: people.avatar ?? ""){ // <-- add this
                PeopleAsyncImageView(url: url)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .mask(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
            }
```

Comment: I already cashed the Url . let me share the code ..

Comment: I added code for Both views

Comment: OK, but you are not using your cached image. Use the cache in this line then: `Image(people.avatar ?? "")`

Comment: I not sure to call it righty. Its expecting the CacheAsyncImage(url: <#T##URL#>, content: <#T##(AsyncImagePhase) -> _#>)

Comment: can you please help ?

Comment: Try the code I posted above. It will use the `PeopleAsyncImageView` which is using `CacheAsyncImage` under the hood to use a cached image if it's available